# Can be use microdata with english for non-english websites?

Tags: html5, microdata, schema.org

My websites is Thai sites (non-english), I'm not sure google can be know or understand my websites in Thai. Can be explain about my websites structure in English by micro data?

I think explain my websites in English is easy than Thai.

Thank you.

Comment: My websites is Thai language. Can be write description in English? I think english is shorten than Thai and google may be understand English better than Thai language.

Comment: Have any tag can be add explain paragraph?

like this <article content="english english">THAI THAI THAI</article>

Comment: Have any tag can be add for simplified content with paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

If Google wouldn't be able to understand your Thai content, so it wouldn't be able too, to rank it and to show it like a search result. So, for first, be sure, it understands your site.

For the second, you should explain the meaning of your site in the site's language. So, if your use Schema.org's inline markup, something like `<span itemprop="description">Description Text</span>`, so write your description text in Thai. But write `itemrpop="description"`in english ;)

Comment: My websites have many beautiful parlance and persuade wording in Thai, It's parlance for sale page, some wording may difficult translate to English by automation translator, may be missing communicate. I'm not sure Google can be know my meaning. I think Google know well with English it's not for Thai. 

If I written only specific, It's not good for sale page.

Thank you for your answer.